# Azure ServiceBus Multiple consumers

Tags: azureservicebus

I have a Azure Servicebus with a single topic and a single subscription. I have a windows service on-premise, that subscribes to this topic and it has filters to pick up messages intended to be run against on-premises DB's. I have a Azure App Service that is subscribed to the same Topic and Subscription. It has filters that match messages that are intended to be run against our cloud services/DB's.

I am seeing inconsistencies, mainly sometimes messages that do not appear to be handled by the consumer intended. Sometimes you will see them in the queue with the delivery count incrementing, then they finally get processed.

Have I misunderstood how Topics work. Do each of these need there own subscription (as well as filters?)?

Answer (score 1):

Every subscriber interested in the message should have its own subscription. Otherwise, you have competing consumers scenario, where the two consumers feed off the same subscription (queue).

Comment: So even though they don't have a filter set for the message they could lock them from the other consumer?

Comment: A topic is a distribution point. A topic knows nothing about the consumers. It merely runs through each subscription's filters and if those are satisfied, places a copy of the message in that subscription. If a subscription is consumed by more than a single process, then those processes compete over the same message. And since it's a single subscription, only one process will get to handle the message. That's why for different **logical** processes there should be a separate subscription.

Comment: Thanks. Since they are filtering for different messages, it seems like it should work, if they shared the subscription, but I have fixed it and I hope this does get rid of the inconsistencies. I will mark this as an answer if we do not see them over the next day or so.